# Multiple sub-domain with several App services in Azure

Tags: redirect, azure-web-app-service, subdomain, wildcard, azure-application-insights

I currently have one App Service with one domain and one wildcard certificate. I have WordPress and using multiple subdomains has worked so far for schools and district. ex District1.contoso.com School1.contoso.com, School2.contoso.com.

Issue now is that the next district has new requirements but we want to use the same domain. This second district will be on a different App Service. Ex. District2.contoso.com, SchoolA.contoso.com, SchoolB.contoso.com, SchoolC.contoso.com.

We have both App Services setup, we have an *Application Gateway with rules and listners and such. We also have a Virtual Machine with IIS to do redirect from an old domain. (Ex. *.oldcontoso.com)

I can't find instructions on how to have the same domain but sub-domains pointing to different App Services. I only found pointing two different domains to two apps but this is not the case.

How do I redirect the sub-domains to different app services. (ps, I expect a repeat with other districts)